# Changing variables' values from class inside of a MonoBehaviour class in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class inside of a MonoBehaviour class' script and i want to change the values of variables that is declared inside it. I tried this but did not work out.

```
public class OuterClass: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public class InnerClass
    {
        public string var1;
        public GameObject var2;
        public int var3;
    }
    public List<InnerClass> innerclass;
}
```

But still i can not acces this variables in my inspector. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing 'SerializeField' with 'Serializable' attribute.

Comment: I miss-remembered the thing. Worked like a charm, thank you so much!